# Как получить данные в select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте уважаемые хотелось бы попросить помощи.
У меня суть вопроса такая мне нужно взять данные из одного блока например #list
и получить их в форме на другой странице в select и как бы я не гадал ни каких идей мне не приходит по этому прощу помощи.

p.s в блоке #list есть разные элементы например `<div>Маша</div> <p>Сережа</p>`

Comment: через метод `GET` пробовали?

Comment: нет не пробовал а как мне с другой страницы получить если можно пример кода или статейку буду очень рад:)

Comment: просто допустим я указываю страницу и блок откуда парсить например $( "#result option:selected" ).load( "/test.html #list" ); не знаю так не так

Comment: просо если сделать так он будет прасить в одну строчку все и будет один пункт который можно будет выбрать но как сделать так что бы выбрать можно было несколько т.е разделить то что он парсит по пунктам

Comment: неужели ни кто не знает ответа ...(((

Comment: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=593 а если все запихнуть в куки и вытаскивать на нужной странице?

Comment: вообщем с куками идея не плохая но не то:) вообщем эти данные находятся в левом меню в определенном пункте одним словом это под меню и мне это под меню нужно брать в форму и получить там список в select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно в пределах **одного** домена выдернуть какие-то строки с различными тегами. Вообще, это ужасно, так делать не надо. Надо искать другие пути. Но если уж очень надо, то код примерно такой:

[Вот работающий пример на JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhpf0gp4/1/)

```html
<div id="test">
    <p>Dio</p>
    <span>Gillan</span><br/>
    <i>Vivaldi</i>
</div>
<hr/>
<select id="testSelect"></select>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#test')
 .find('*')
 .each(function(index, item){
    var text = $(item).text().trim();
    if (text.length > 0){           
        $('#testSelect').append(new Option(text, text));
    }
 });

</script>
```

Как видите, внутри #test случайные теги. Предполагается, что внутри тегов нужный элемент списка.

С помощью jQuery берем содержимое #test, выбираем все элементы и перебираем его. Проверяем каждый элемент, чтобы строка без пробелов была больше нуля. И добавляем тэг  в список #testSelect

Если же требуется скриптом у клиента дергать данные со страницы другого домена, то так не будет работать вообще.